# Firestore arrayUnion on aggragated array of objects?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to `arrayUnion` the `votes` field from the following document:

```
{
  answers: [
    {
      title: "title"
      votes: [
        "id1",
        "id2",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**It's important to me to use `arrayUnion` since I need to use an atomic operation** (in case a user goes offline and then back online).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `answers` field is an array value, you'll need to specify the *entire* value of the array item when using `arrayUnion` on that field. There is no way to use an `arrayUnion` operation on the nested `votes` subfield in there, as that'd be providing a partial update to an array item, which isn't a supported operation.

So you'll have to :

1. Read the document and get the entire `answers` field from it into your application code.
2. Modify the correct array item with the new `votes` subvalue.
3. Write the entire array back to the database.

Comment: Hey @Frank, your suggestion is not an atomic operation. I need to use `arrayUnion` in order to apply changes for back-online users. Any Idea for a better document structure?

Comment: You can read and write the document in a transaction, which would make it atomic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the documentation mentions that `Transactions will fail when the client is offline`. I don't want my users to fail, I want them to work directly through the cache, and when getting online, do an atomic update (transaction). Can you please suggest a better structure, in order to use `ArrayUnion`?

Comment: You keep coming back to an array union, but that isn't possible here since you are trying to **update** an item in an array, which isn't a union operation.